# Altair plotting realtime data Python

Tags: python, real-time, altair

how to plot realtime using Altair in Python?
I have 1 grouped data by 'groupby' pandas. I don't know how to plot altair realtime with grouped data realtime.
This is my code:

```
import mainData
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('altair_viewer')
import time

while True:
  mainData.realTime()
  chart0 = alt.Chart(mainData.grouped.get_group(0, obj=None).reset_index()).transform_fold(mainData.grouped.get_group(0, obj=None).columns.tolist(), as_=['quote', 'price']).mark_line().encode(x='index:T', y='price:Q', color='quote:N')
  chart1 = alt.Chart(mainData.grouped.get_group(1, obj=None).reset_index()).transform_fold(mainData.grouped.get_group(1, obj=None).columns.tolist(), as_=['quote', 'price']).mark_line().encode(x='index:T', y='price:Q', color='quote:N')
  chart2 = alt.Chart(mainData.grouped.get_group(2, obj=None).reset_index()).transform_fold(mainData.grouped.get_group(2, obj=None).columns.tolist(), as_=['quote', 'price']).mark_line().encode(x='index:T', y='price:Q', color='quote:N')
  chart3 = alt.Chart(mainData.grouped.get_group(3, obj=None).reset_index()).transform_fold(mainData.grouped.get_group(3, obj=None).columns.tolist(), as_=['quote', 'price']).mark_line().encode(x='index:T', y='price:Q', color='quote:N')
  chart4 = alt.Chart(mainData.grouped.get_group(4, obj=None).reset_index()).transform_fold(mainData.grouped.get_group(4, obj=None).columns.tolist(), as_=['quote', 'price']).mark_line().encode(x='index:T', y='price:Q', color='quote:N')
  chart5 = alt.Chart(mainData.grouped.get_group(5, obj=None).reset_index()).transform_fold(mainData.grouped.get_group(5, obj=None).columns.tolist(), as_=['quote', 'price']).mark_line().encode(x='index:T', y='price:Q', color='quote:N')
  alt.vconcat(alt.hconcat(chart0, chart1, chart2), alt.hconcat(chart3, chart4, chart5)).show()
  time.sleep(0.2)
```

I have ploted a chart display on a webpage already, but the show() blocking my loop, so I cannot recreate grouped data in while Loop.
grouped data is global variable in mainData.realtime().
How to display Altair's chart on browser without show()? Or how to use Altair in while loop to plotting chart realtime?
Thank you in advance.
Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('altair_viewer')

while True:
   df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
   chart0 = alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).transform_fold(df.columns.tolist(), as_=['quote', 'price']).mark_line().encode(x='index:T', y='price:Q', color='quote:N')
   chart0.show()
   print("1")
   time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: In order to better assist, can you show what you have tried so far and where you have failed or hit an error message please ?

Comment: thank @D.L, i have edited my question, please help me if you know how to use altair plotting realtime on webpage.

Comment: i have not yet, but i will be looking into this.  Here is a good video t follow if you have 45 mins:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-iU2UwgVf0&ab_channel=HacktheNorth

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example that others can try to run? Altair charts have methods such as `.to_html()` that might be helpful depending on the context you are using this in.

Comment: thank @joelostblom, i added an example. show chart on browser but bloking by alt.show() and cannot print('1') .I just want plotting chart realtime. I have take a look at .to_html() and .to_json(), maybe that will way goes on. If you have showcase to use .to_json() for chart realtime, please give me an example. Thank Joelostblom so much.

Answer (score 1):

I have already my answer, Altair using with Streamlit for plotting chart real-time. Thank you buddies :D. I following this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-animations-in-altair-and-streamlit-2a0624789ad.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
def draw(df):
  chart = alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).transform_fold(df.columns.tolist(), as_=['quote', 'price']).mark_line().encode(x='index:T', y='price:Q')
  return chart

draw(df)
realTimeChart = st.altair_chart(chart)

while True:
  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
  draw(df)
  realTimeChart = realTimeChart.altair_chart(chart)
  time.sleep(0.2)
```